# Mocha showing whole unit test is failed

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

i am doing unit testing in Node js with Express js and for testing i am using mocha and for mocking of data i am using sinon. Everything is fine but my problem is when i run the test case if the `it()` contains multiple assertions and anyone of them got failed then the mocha shows that the whole `it()` is failed. But i want the other assertion to passed even though any one fails. **I don't want to write one it() for each field**. My test code is

```
//loading testing dependencies
var request = require('supertest');
var server = require('./app');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var sinon = require("sinon");
var should = chai.should();

//configuring chai
chai.use(chaiHttp);

//ORM controller (we need to mock data in it's method)
var rootController = require('./app/controllers/users/users_controller');

//Writing test cases
describe('loading express', function () {
    //mock data before each request
    before(function(){
      //select the method of the ORM controller which you want to mock
      sinon.stub(rootController, "get", //get is the method of ORM's customers_controller'
      function(req, res, next){
        //response object which we are going to mock
          var response = {};
          response.status = 'success',
          response.data = {
            userId: '0987654321@ef',
            userName:'John'
          };
          next(response);
      });
    });
  it('responds to /users/getUserData', function testMethod(done) {
    //call server file (app.js)
    request(server)
      //send request to the Express route which you want to test
      .get('/users/getUserData?id=0987654321')
      //write all expactions here
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        console.log("Generated response is ", res.body);
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('object');
        //res.body.status.should.equal("success");
        res.body.data.userId.should.equal("0987654321@ef347389");
        res.body.data.userName.should.equal("John");
        //done is the callback of mocha framework
        done();
      });

  });

  it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200, done);
  });

  it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/foo/bar')
      .expect(404, done)

  });

});
```

You can see here my userId should be failed and userName should be passed but when i run this code it says that **responds to /users/getCustomerData** got failed. Instead of it mocha should say that userId field got failed and userName field got passed.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how Mocha and `should` work: when an assertion fails, `should` throws an error, which means that the rest of the code (including any subsequent assertions) won't be executed.

You can rewrite your test so that the request is only done once, but that each assertion is still tested separately:

```
describe('responds to /users/getUserData', function testMethod(done) {
  let reqErr, reqRes;

  before(function(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/users/getUserData?id=0987654321')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        reqErr = err;
        reqRes = res;
        done();
      });
  });

  it('should have the correct body type', function() {
    reqRes.body.should.be.a('object');
  });

  it('should have the correct userId', function() {
    reqRes.body.data.userId.should.equal("0987654321@ef347389");
  });

  it('should have the correct userName', function() {
    reqRes.body.data.userName.should.equal("John");
  });

});
```

Comment: You mean i need to write one it() for each field? is there any other option available?

Comment: If you want to see the separate tests failing or passing, then they should be made into separate `it()`'s. No way around it AFAIK.